# Installing SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I'm just looking for some advice on this. I just started a new job. My understanding was we would be using SharePoint Enterprise 2010, so I downloaded SharePoint Designer 2010. Since then, we decided to move on to SharePoint Enterprise 2013. Should I completely uninstall SharePoint Designer 2010 before installing SharePoint Designer 2013?

I've really not used SharePoint Designer 2010 at all, since we have not completed the SP server install yet. So I do not have any sites set up in SharePoint Designer 2010. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to completely uninstall SP Designer 2010 to install 2013, however with the latest patch the 2010 one will not run anyway with 2013 on the system.

Make sure you have the appropriate version of office installed on the system as well.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. I may need to use SP Designer 2010, but Depends on whether we move a few existing old sites from SP 2010 to SP 2013.

Answer (score 2):

Yes uninstalling SP Designer 2010 is preferred in your situation.. than install SP Designer 2013, make sure you use the 64-bit version for Office and SharePoint Designer both!